# Etymology of axioma and axis

Tags: etymology

Is it possible that "axis" and "axioma" (English "axiom") derive from the same etymological root?

From a superficial search, it at least seems possible that the PIE root *ag "to move" (i.e. *axiom: to move about ~*) could translate across. However, I could find no explicit evidence that they were related etymologically.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=a&p=65&allowed_in_frame=0) gives different PIE roots for these two words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible that Latin *axis* (whence English *axis*) and Greek *axiôma* (whence English *axiom*) are from the same Proto-Indo-European root, **h2eg-* "to lead".

---

**Chantraine** describes the development of Greek *axiôma* from the verb *axioô*:

[image]

About the ultimate etymology of the root, he suggests that it is rightly connected with the verb *ago* "to lead, bring, carry, weigh":

[image]

---

**De Vaan** gives **h2eks-(i-)* "axle, arm-pit" as the Proto-Indo-European root of Latin *axis*:

[image]

He also adds that this root may be derived from the Proto-Indo-European root **h2eg-* "to lead", which is the root of the Latin verb *ago*, which has in turn the same origin as the Greek verb *agô* that Chantraine suggests as the origin of the Greek verb above:

[image]